# in my app login with email and password also google works but signout in both cases does not work

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, dart, google-signin

in my notes page when I click sign out, I get uid was called on null error, But I do have the stream to check whether the user is signed in or out, so according to that it should return form page or notes page, but when I click signOut it is not working.

```
ERROR

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Notespage(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<FirebaseUser>], state: _NotespageState#662ef):
The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: uid

The relevant error-causing widget was
    Notespage 
lib\route.dart:26
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _NotespageState.build 
package:first_app/screens/notes.dart:33
#2      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4619
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4502
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4675
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

main.dart

```
import (...)

// ...

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

// ...

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
      value: AuthInstance().user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: HomePage(),
        // MaterialApp contains our top-level Navigator
        initialRoute: '/wrapper',
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.indigo,
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              'wrapper',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none),
            ))),
        onTap: () {
          return Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/wrapper');
        });
  }
}
```

.\auth.dart(Authentication of users)

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class AuthInstance {
  String name;
  String email;
  String imageUrl;

  Stream<FirebaseUser> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged;
  }

  Future signIn() async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future signout() async {
    try {
      await GoogleSignIn().signOut();

      await _auth.signOut();

      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future registerInwithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future signInwithGoogle() async {
    try {
      GoogleSignInAccount _googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

      GoogleSignInAuthentication _googleauth = await _googleUser.authentication;
      final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
        accessToken: _googleauth.accessToken,
        idToken: _googleauth.idToken,
      );
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      assert(!user.isAnonymous);
      assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

      final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
      assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

      assert(user.email != null);
      assert(user.displayName != null);
      assert(user.photoUrl != null);

      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future signinwithEmail(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> resetPassword(String email) async {
    await _auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: email);
  }
}
```

a wrapper which shows either Login or information page ./wrapper.dart

```
import (...)

class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const Wrapper({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);

    if (user == null) {
      return FormPage();
    } else {
      return Infopage();
    }
  }
}
```

./NotesPage

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class Notespage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotespageState createState() => _NotespageState();
}

class _NotespageState extends State<Notespage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    final user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context);

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('notes')
          .document(user.uid)
          .collection('notes-user')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                'Loading...',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            );
          default:
            return Scaffold(
                   body:Container(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                            child: Text('LogOut'), 
                            onPressed: () async{
                            _auth.signout(),
                 }),
             );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an error. It's `_auth.signOut()` , 'O' is uppercase

and try this,

```
class Notespage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotespageState createState() => _NotespageState();
}

class _NotespageState extends State<Notespage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
      builder: (context, futureSnapshot) {
        if (futureSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        else
          return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('notes')
                .document(futureSnapshot.data.uid)
                .collection('notes-user')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Loading...',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  );
                default:
                  return Scaffold(
                    body:Container(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Text('LogOut'),
                          onPressed: () async{
                            _auth.signOut(),
                          }),
                    ),
                  );
              }
            },
          );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: error is after changing the signout -> signOut , evev after changing i get the same error

Comment: i didn't properly understand provider model class, but I have imported provider and used Stream Provider around main.dart file, and stream is in auth.dart.

Comment: and all the code for main and auth.dart is shared above.

Comment: can you pls tell, where is the mistake

Comment: Why do you want to implement signin, signout other related methods in the class, try to do it without class if it is not necessary

Comment: no it didn't , when i debug it step by step after signOut it is not making user as null.